# Hotline Miami Style Rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to animate the following image with jQuery: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFHVG.png so it looks like it's moving similar to how the floating heads in Hotline Miami move (From side to side) whenever someone mouses over the content.

For an example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uk3m0XaP_Yo

I've been attempting to adjust it with CSS properties but I haven't been very successful. For an example of what I was using click here: http://jsfiddle.net/WhZym/1256/

```
var rotation = 0;

jQuery.fn.rotate = function(degrees) {
    $(this).css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 'transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)'});
};

$('.rotate').mouseover(function() {
    rotation += 5;
    $(this).rotate(rotation);
});
```

I'd like to make it so it fires the animations while someones mouse is on the content, and then resets the position of the image back to default when it leaves.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need Javascript for this, just use CSS animations.

Comment: Good point. I'm over complicating things here. Thanks for the advice!